# Auto email based on column values with confirmation

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I want to send an email to each person in row 3 column B:D, whose email address is in row 2 when:

- The row = today's date (in B2) and
- The value in that row for each column (B:D) is > 0.

  - If =0 or blank then ignore, move to next column.

Number should also be used in body of email e.g. if there was a 2 then:

> Hi London,
>
> You've performed really well and will get 2 presents!
>
> Regards,
>
> Santa

Once looped through all columns (B:D) and emails sent, then in column E type "Y" to illustrate to document viewers that the confirmation email has been sent.

See example for the layout: [image: example layout].
There won't be duplicate dates in column A.

Comment: This has been done before. Please do a search.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow!
This isn't a complete code solution, but some pointers:

- "... to each person in ... " - sounds like you need a `For Each` loop or similar, google 'vba loops' to see what I'm on about. A loop is a piece of code that runs multiple times, only changing one variable each time (in your case the variable would be which column is being looked at, and the loop should run 3 times). Loops prevent unnecessary duplication of code, making it easier to read and edit code later on.
- "when the row = today's date" - google 'vba if statement', pretty straightforward. Today's date can be detected in vba as `Date`.
- "Number should be used in body of email" - what you're saying is, the body of the email is variable, not a fixed text. You'll need to create a string variable to hold the information `Dim strBody As String` near the start of your process, then in each loop create or build up this string, something like:

```
strBody = "Hello" & vbcrlf & "You've performed really well and will get " & LNumberVariable & " presents"
```

- You can treat the creating and sending of an email as a separate task to all the things you're doing within the excel sheet to decide whether an email should be sent, what it should contain, etc. Do this by calling a separate sub with parameters. I have a standard sub I use for this, copied from various bits of the internet and adapted a bit myself:

```
Sub SendEmail(Optional ToAddresses As String, Optional CcAddresses As String, _
Optional BccAddresses As String, Optional Subject As String, _
Optional Body As String, Optional AttachFiles As Variant = False, Optional AutoSend As Boolean = False, _
Optional SendFromAddress As String)
'Adapted from https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail4.htm

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    
    'Current application, where applicable;
    On Error GoTo Err
    Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
NoErr:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
    
    'Basic Text properties
        .To = ToAddresses
        .CC = CcAddresses
        .Bcc = BccAddresses
        .Subject = Subject
    '---------------------
            
    'Body; HTML or plain text
        If Body Like "*<br>*" Then
            .HtmlBody = Body
        Else
            .Body = Body
        End If
     '---------------------
            
    'Attachments:
        If Not AttachFiles = False Then
            If IsArray(AttachFiles) Then
                For x = LBound(AttachFiles) To UBound(AttachFiles)
                    .Attachments.Add (AttachFiles(x))
                Next
            Else
                .Attachments.Add (AttachFiles)
            End If
        End If
    '---------------------
            
    'Sender Address
        If Len(SendFromAddress) > 0 Then
            For a = 1 To OutApp.Session.accounts.Count
                If LCase(OutApp.Session.accounts.Item(a)) Like LCase(SendFromAddress) Then
                    .sendusingaccount = OutApp.Session.accounts.Item(a)
                    SendFromAddress = ""
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            If Len(SendFromAddress) > 0 Then .SentOnBehalfOfName = SendFromAddress
        End If
   '---------------------
            
    'Send or display:
        If AutoSend = True Then
            .Send
        Else
            .Display
        End If
    '---------------------
            
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
Exit Sub
Err:
        If Err.Number = 429 Then
            Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
            GoTo NoErr
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        Err.Raise (Err.Number)
End Sub
```

If the above is in your project, you can call it like

```
Call SendEmail(ToAddresses:="me@example.com;you@example.com", Subject:="my Test email", Body:=myStringBodyVariable, AutoSend:=True)
```

or

```
Call SendEmail("me@example.com", , , "Subject line here", "Body text would appear here", , False)
```

All the parameters are optional so you can just include which ones you need/like. Running from Excel, it will need you to set up reference to the outlook library so it can run outlook code within the excel application.

- My final tip would be to review your sheet layout a bit. You currently have 3 addresses to send to, laid out next to each other with other information either side blocking them in. If at any point you decide to add a fourth email address, or change the trigger for one of them (e.g. ' if row date was yesterday...') then you'll have to change both the sheet and the code quite substantially. Think about what changes you might wish to make to the data/process in future, and make sure the layout and code will easily acommodate those (so if your loop is going across, but that column E is blocking it in, maybe shift column E's contents to a row below instead so additional data could be spread as far across as needed without having to shift the 'Y' mark everytime you add information?). I use a spreadsheet that sends automatic reminder emails to our company's staff - in mine, each row is an email to send, with a column for the recipient, email text, date to send on, and some other relevant variables. That way my loop just processes one entire row at a time.

I know that's a lot to read, but I hope the tips help!

Comment: Thank you so much for all the pointers! I shall get started :)